# Which hash function is used when converting an address from raw bytes?

Tags: address, hash, types, string, base58

With the raw address `0x0000861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316` the first 4 characters (0000 in this case) represent `tz1` and the rest of the string is the raw Tezos address.

From my research it appears that the rest of the bytes, `861299624c9a3b52be10762c64bac282b1c02316` must get hashed before it can be converted to a string with base58 but I am not sure which of the available hashing algorithms I should use to do so.

Which algo should I be using to get these bytes into the pre-base58 hashed byte form? (i.e. the state *before* converting that data to its final form of `XrwX7i9Nzh8e6UmG3VnFkAeoyWdTqDf3U` with base58)

Is it blake2b?

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/encoding-of-addresses-in-optimized-micheline-representation.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not hashed. You simply need to compute the base58 translation with the right prefix.

Proof that it’s not hashed: this process is reversible.

Comment: this is the answer that caused my confusion: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/3069/7981 - does this mean that the answer to that question is misleading?

Comment: This answer is also correct. KT1 addresses do involve hashing (blake2b if I remember well). However, conversions between byte representation and addresses don’t involve hashing.

Comment: so the raw bytes represent a hash of an address when it is a KT1, but represents an unhashed address when it is a tz addresses?

Comment: The address is itself a plain regular hash for KT1, whether written KT1…. or in bytes. Those are representations of the same thing. Tz* accounts are related to the underlying keys, no blake2b involved.